# Using the beta function in scipy.stats

Tags: python, scipy

Sorry to start another question, but I'm not sure I'm going to get any more responses in my previous question's page.

I was just wondering how to evaluate the [beta function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.beta.html) at specific values.

```
from scipy.stats import beta

print(beta.pdf(1.5, 1,25))
print(beta(1, 25).pdf(1.5))
```

I get
`0.0` and `0.0`

That can't be right. So what's the right way to do this?

Thanks

P.S. What happened to the reply button to comments and answers to my questions? I can't find it anymore. I can post new replies, but I don't think those result in little red notifications to the people who respond to my question (right)?

Answer (score 0):

`x` parameter (the first one) must be between 0 and 1. The value of `beta` is typically 0 above 1.0.

For me, the comments work.